# Continuous Delivery - Microservices Release/Versioning

Tags: docker, jenkins, microservices, continuous-delivery, kubernetes-helm

We are developing Microservices using Spring Boot which are than packaged up as Helm Charts and deployed onto a Kubernetes cluster. Each service has a Jenkinsfile and we have been releasing each service individually below:

- Service A --> Build --> Package --> QA --> Staging --> Production
- Service B --> Build --> Package --> QA --> Staging --> Production
- Service C --> Build --> Package --> QA --> Staging --> Production

This approach is fairly straight forward but it doesn't actually give you a shippable artifact and you end up with inconsistencies.

What we would like to do is group the release using an umbrella Helm chart shown below (Parent A):

- Parent A --> Build --> Package --> QA --> Staging --> Production

  - Service A
  - Service B
  - Service C

I'm struggling to think of a way to do this without having to manually release each service, then update the versions in the parent chart. Is anyone doing this in an automated way?

Answer (score 2):

I can share a simplified view on how we ship code [Codefresh](http://codefresh.io):

- each microservice has it's own git repo and helm chart.
- each service codebase is versioned (regardless of the chart), for example in `package.json`.
- each helm chart is also versioned.
- When devs update services, they must bump the version in the code.
- We also have one Helm uber-chart that lists all of the microservices charts as [chart requirements](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_best_practices/requirements.md).
- CI pipeline on the code repo builds a docker image (tagged with the code version) and a helm chart (tagged with the code version). This doesn't deploy anything yet.
- If a dev wants to deploy, they edit the requirements file in the uber-chart, requiring the new version.
- CD pipeline on the uber-chart does a helm upgrade.

This is a very simplified description. In reality the pipeline also does stuff like:

- auto handling of npm and github releases
- gates based on semver scope of update
- automatic provisioning of ad-hoc environments on PR/branch (spin up a new environment to test/share your change)
- secret management

To be honest this is not a simple pipeline, but hey, we are a CI/CD company so this is our bread and butter.
We are often asked by customers to share more about the work we've done, and even replicate it for a customer, which we happily do. Feel free to ping me.

Comment: This in essence is the approach that we have taken too. I (am trying to) view this as a benefit - you have an exact and exact track of what is deployed, because you have to manually update the sub-chart versions in your uber chart and rebuild it.

Comment: So basically each ms has its own chart, so everytime a ms is modified, you upgrade the ms version and the chart version. I still think the one-chart many releases it is the way to go for many similar microservices. But I agree that is in theory. I'm also looking a way to do latter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your problem, you could solve it by using the Jenkins multijob plugin. And without updating your current existing job.

Your workflow would look like:

```
Parent Job
    Service A --> Build --> Package --> QA --> Staging --> Production
    Service B --> Build --> Package --> QA --> Staging --> Production
    Service C --> Build --> Package --> QA --> Staging --> Production
```

Where your parent job trigger all your child jobs.

I have seen a similar problem solved this way. Also sometime your child service must be released together, or one of your service must always be ahead (server). You can add some python/shell validation scripts in your parent job in order to make sure that your final product is always releasable.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin